# In Angular @Input() doesn't work for the simplest hardcoded string input

Tags: angular, input, rxjs, push, parent-child

I have admin.users.list.html as the parent template, which inputs some data to the child component:

```
<general-entities-list-container *ngIf="{
    entityType: entityType$ | async
} as asyncData"
  [entityType]='asyncData.entityType'
  [entityTypeHardCoded]="'users'"
  [entityTypeSet]="'users'"
  >
</general-entities-list-container>
```

I have general-entity-list-container.html (child template):

```
entityType is:{{ entityType }} <br/>
entityTypeSet is:{{ entityTypeSet }} <br/>
entityTypeSet_ is:{{ entityTypeSet_ }} <br/>
entityTypeHardCoded is:{{ entityTypeHardCoded }} <br/>
```

admin.users.list.ts:

```
entityType$: Observable<string> = of('users');
```

general-entity-list-container.ts has:

```
@Input() entityType: string;
@Input() entityTypeHardCoded: string;

entityTypeSet_: string;
    
@Input() set entityTypeSet(cet: string) {
  this.entityTypeSet_ = cet;
  //this.handleChangeCurrentEntityType(cet);
}
get entityTypeSet(){
  return this.entityTypeSet_;
}
```

I cannot get the out put absolutely anywhere in the child component template. What is the catch here. I am using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` on both parent and child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your *ngIf will always return true (it checks if the asyncData object is defined, but you're actually defining it, so that will be true). If you're trying to group together your async pipe subscriptions then better to use that *ngIf in a top wrapper element and then in your child element you can use

```
*ngIf="asyncData.entityType"
```

Something like:

```
<div *ngIf="{
  entityType: entityType$ | async
} as asyncData"
    <child-component 
        *ngIf="asyncData.entityType" 
        [entityType]="asyncData.entityType">
    </child-component>
</div>
```

Then I see a single quotation, should be double:

```
[entityType]='asyncData.entityType'
```

Should be:

```
[entityType]="asyncData.entityType"
```

Other than that, it works on stackblitz. So there must be something else wrong. Either importing components in to modules, importing modules in to modules, referencing the wrong templates in the component etc. But it seems Angular input still work :)

I recommend you try on stackblitz first and check what else might be wrong in your components/modules setup. The issue is there, not in the inputs.

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zgqtey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html[][1]](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zgqtey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: the issue at the end was because of the circula dependency between modules, most probably.